# How to bind Json parameters to Web Api parameters in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When I have this method in an MVC Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> MyMethod(int param1, string param2)
{
   //....
}
```

I can send a Json object `{param1:1, param2:"str"}` it works just fine and parameters are resolved. However when I do this for a WebApi 2 it doesn't work. Because `[FromBody]` can only be used by 1 parameter according to following example on documentation.

```
At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body
    // Caution: Will not work!    
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

How can we obtain the same behavior of MVC controller from WebApi controller?

**Edit**: Creating corresponding classes and replacing parameters is not an option, because a messaging tool checks these methods for maintenance. Signatures should remain the same.

Comment: You edit provides not possible task - max one parameter can be read from body as: "The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a non-buffered stream that can only be read once."

Comment: @VadimLevkovsky You are absolutely right.However, since the signature stays the same, I just made the method accept both GET and POST. When we send GET with paramters in url, it works.

Comment: not being able to do this is a pain in the bum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to compose one object from these values:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int name {get;set;}
}

public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Foo foo) 
{
    //some stuff...
}
```

If signature should remain the same, you can try to specify params in url, like that: `myurl?id=1&name=Tom` still via POST verb.

Comment: Signature should remain the same because a messaging infrastructure checks those controller methods time to time. I'll edit my question with this detail.

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]dynamic value)
{
    int id= value.id.ToString();
    string name = value.name.ToString();
}
```

And pass json like following

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"abc"
}
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic for such things, as you usually know what data you get from front-end.

Comment: Yes, but if you don't wont to create new class for just passing value to the one method, and you have many methods in a controller, so what will you do?

Comment: I do create classes. All requests/responses are something that may have semantical (or even physical) value - domain objects. Why don't expose them explicitly as classes? If there are lot of classes that has no meaning - I'd treat it as code smell and think about API refactoring .

Answer (score 1):

If you have to pass multiple parameter please **use class object**:

```
public class PortalClass
{
    public ApplicationModel applicationModel { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public object pageCollection { get; set; }
}

public object GetApplication(PortalClass data)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All, PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None };
    var myObject=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PageCollection>(data.pageCollection.ToString(), settings)
    return null;
}
```

**Client Side:**

```
var data = {
    user_id: userId,
    id: id
};

http.post(url, data).then(
   function (response) {

}, function (err) {
   callback.reject(err);
});
```

Comment: Signature should remain the same because a messaging infrastructure checks those controller methods time to time.